# How to get the row id after DB::insert in Lumen/Laravel with basic queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm using **Lumen 5.1** and running raw SQL queries, using the `DB` facade.

How can I get the row's id after performed an `insert` query?

For example:

```
$rowId = DB::insert("insert into `customers` (name) values ('Tom')");
echo $rowId; // 1
```

The variable `$rowId` should then contains the db row's id.

Comment: Is there a row in the table setup to be an `auto increment` column?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, the table `customers` is setted with `auto increment` on the `id` column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have to get a handle to the underlying PDO object and then us that to get the new insert id like so

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();

$result = DB::insert("insert into `customers` (name) values ('Tom')");

if ( $result )  {
    $rowId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Or maybe even simplier

```
$result = DB::insert("insert into `customers` (name) values ('Tom')");
if ( $result )  {
    $rowId = DB::connection() -> getPdo() -> lastInsertId();
}
```

*Not tested, just extrapolated from the manual*

Comment: Sorry, I was busy. I tried it and it seems to working. Great! Thank you very much!